# notepad++ move closing tag down two lines when pressing enter

Tags: plugins, notepad++, auto-indent

I'm using notepad++ version 6.1. I have the TextFX plugin installed to auto close my tags once inserted. I then installed the Indent By Fold plugin to indent on enter. My problem is between tags, it moves the closing tag down one line, as well as indenting it. I would like to move the closing tag down two lines (without indent) and only indent the line between the open and closing tags.

This is what happens currently when pressing enter between open and closing tags:

```
<table>
     </table>
```

This is what i'm trying to get when pressing enter between closing tags:

```
<table>
     Indent starts here
</table>
```